# Selección de cadena de caracteres en strings.xml a partir de una variable String - Android Studio

Tags: android, string, studio

He definido una serie de cadenas en el documento strings.xml. Dependiendo de una selección de un spinner, debo seleccionar una cadena u otra.

Necesito hacer algo como esto:

```
String selection_array="R.array."+spinner-selection;
String[] str_array = getResources().getStringArray(selection_array);
```

Pero no puedo usar una cadena en el argumento de getResources (). GetStringArray

Tengo que usar una selección estática:

```
String[] str_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.region1_array);
```

Y eso significa usar muchas declaraciones condicionales (if, else if)

¿Que puedo hacer?

Esta es la cadenas definidas en strings.xml

```
<string-array name="region1_array">
<item>Region 1</item>
<item>Region 2</item>
<item>Region 3</item>
</string-array>


<string-array name="region2_array">
<item>Region 4</item>
<item>Region 5</item>
<item>Region 6</item>
</string-array>

. 
. 
.
<string-array name="regionN_array">
<item>Region N-2</item>
<item>Region N-1</item>
<item>Region N</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

En Android existe un método que para retornar el identificador de tus recurso utilizando el nombre. Entonces una vez se tenga el identificador puedes utilizar la funcion `getResources().getStringArray(IDENTIFICADOR);` para mostrar ella array que deseas.

Ejemplo para array `region1_array`

```
int arrayResId = resources.getIdentifier("region1_array", "array", getPackageName())
if (arrayResId != 0) {
    //Verificamos que el id que nos devuelve sea diferente de 0 para asignar el valor. No olvidar que si devuelve 0, significa que no existe el recurso
   String[] str_array = getResources().getStringArray(arrayResId);
}
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Gracias. Pero en resources.getIdentifier() , "region1_array" sigue siendo una constante de caracteres. Yo necesito que sea una variable String. ¿Por qué? Pues porque en esa variable string tengo el nombre de la cadena de caracteres de strings.xml que el usuario seleccionó.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad puedes obtener 3 variables enteras que serían los id de recurso de cada array:

```
int array1 = getResources().getIdentifier("region1_array", "array", 
getPackageName());

int array2 = getResources().getIdentifier("region2_array", "array", 
getPackageName());

int array3 = getResources().getIdentifier("region3_array", "array", 
getPackageName());
```

En base a esto puedes decidir cual cargar por ejemplo de acuerdo a una variable de posición:

```
String[] str_array = null;

switch(position) {
    case 0:
        str_array = getResources().getStringArray(array1);
        break;
    case 1:
        str_array = getResources().getStringArray(array2);
        break;
    case 3:
        str_array = getResources().getStringArray(array3);
        break;
    default:
        str_array = getResources().getStringArray(array1);
        break;
}
```